# Replace Wildfly 10 homepage with a custom application contained in an ear file

Tags: jboss, ear, wildfly-10, undertow

I'm trying to replace the Wildfly 10 default homepage (accessed from http://hostname:port) by one of my own web application.
I found a good way to do it by removing some parts of the undertow subsystem of the standalone.xml of my wildfly and by adding a war to the default-web-module.
My problem is that I don't have a war, I have a ear (with a war in it), and it doesn't work with that.

Hereunder is the undertow part of my standalone.xml file :

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
        <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost" default-web-module="myear.ear/mywar.war">
            <access-log pattern="%{i,X-Forwarded-For} %h %{i,SM_UNIVERSALID} %t %H %p %U %q %s %D %T" prefix="http-in" suffix=".log"/>
        </host>
    </server>
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config/>
        <websockets/>
    </servlet-container>            
    <filters>
        <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/10"/>
        <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
    </filters>
</subsystem>
```

Can this solution work with an ear instead of a war, or have I to find another way ?

Thank you in advance,

Seb

Comment: Did you try just using `default-web-module="myear.ear"` and setting the `<context-root>/</context-root>` for the module in your `application.xml`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it by redirecting the index.html page of the welcome-content folder of WildFly to my application, it's simpler and it works perfectly.

Seb